# line break not working for me in ADF pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have tried to write an array variable to file by adding an additional column with @join(array, '\r\n') but it returns

```
filename2
AR-23-CA-23030949-01-80914248.json \r\n AR-23-CA-23031077-01-80914244.json
```

I would like each name on seperate row. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the expression is given as `@join(variables('FileNames'),'\r\n')` , the Json representation of the pipeline activity looks like, `@join(variables('FileNames'),'\\r\\n')`.  You can edit the Json activity and replace `\\r\\n` to `\r\n`. By this way, you can use the line break as delimiter in `Join` function.

[image: gif1]

You can also use the below expression for line break.

`@join(variables('FileNames'), decodeUriComponent('%0D%0A'))`

`%0D%0A` is the URL-encoded representation of the `\r\n` character sequence, so using `decodeUriComponent('%0D%0A')` is equivalent to using `\r\n` directly.